# Styling Shopify emails

Tags: css, email, shopify

So Gmail doesn't show embedded styles. But Shopify email with embedded styling looks styled as expected. My question is does Shopify preprocess its emails templates to turn embedded styles to inline?

Comment: This question don't show any code so its quite hard to tell any thing http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/

Comment: If you can't say anything without code maybe you shouldn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All mail clients read and interprete mail in their own way.

Shopify displays the content as webpage in a browser.

It is therefore much more difficult to code a beautiful mail that a beautiful website.

There are several "good practice" to make pretty mail (the best is not to use div but tables)

You can find some doc on table [here](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2007/07/tables-in-html-emails-nesting/)

And a summary of all the web tools and their compatibility to the mail clients [here](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/selectors/id/).

And doc about font in mail [here](https://templates.mailchimp.com/design/typography/)

Comment: Thank you. The second link is especially useful. What do you mean by "Shopify displays the content as a browser"? When you hit Preview? Yesterday I figured out that Shopify emails show with a default system font

Comment: Yes exactly, like a webpage in a browser. For font you can find information here : https://templates.mailchimp.com/design/typography/